# Trying to remove chromium getting and getting read only file system error

Tags: snap, chromium

I am running Ubuntu LTS 20.04.2

I installed chromium and chrome, I now want to delete chrome. I see chromium in `~/snap/chromium` so I delete it using `rm -rf ~/snap/chromium`, but I still see chromium in the applications menu. When I click on it chromium opens and then I see `chromium` BACK in `~/snap`.

I tried deleting it and restarting with no luck. After I restart chromium is still in the applications menu and when I click on it a folder.

If I try `sudo rm -rf /snap/chromium` i get a bunch of errors similar to the following,

```
rm: cannot remove '/snap/chromium/1536/usr/share/themes/Emacs/gtk-3.0/gtk-keys.css': Read-only file system
```

Now chromium is broken but i'd really like to remove those files and understand whats wrong.

Comment: Title says remove chromium question says chrome which one is it you are trying to remove? Please fix the wording it is very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong way to uninstall a snap, as you have discovered.

Try `sudo snap remove chromium` instead.

---

**Pro Tip**: You shouldn't be using `rm` with ANY files that were installed by a package manager. Doing so is an easy way to break your system quite badly. Always use the appropriate package manager to uninstall software.